# Minor alignment issue in Stack Overflow logo on Stack Overflow for Teams emails footer

Tags: bug, email, logo, stack-overflow-for-teams

I have received a few emails related to Stack Overflow for teams with the subject title started as "Welcome ...", "Build your team, ...", "Find what you need, ...".
In all the email's footers, the below content is displayed:

[image: Footer]

The bottom left part of the Stack Overflow logo is truncated in all the email footer sections. When inspecting the logo elements using the browser's developer tools, being able to see `border-radius: 7px` was applied to the logo that caused the truncated issue.

[image: Border Radius 7px]

Changing the `border-radius: 0px` solved the truncated issue. This is not a major issue, but the logo should be displayed fully.

[image: Border Radius 0px]

Note: I commented out the `border-radius: 7px` from the CSS `style` class, but that has not solved the issue.